# Final bit on program I can't get working. (Constructors)

Tags: java, constructor, instance-variables

This is the last code section of my program and I can't make it work:

The problem is that when I print out, the program uses the `words` instance variable.

How can I change the code so I can use the wordList instead in the main method below? Is it something I have to change in the Constructor?

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Sentence {
private String[] words = {""}; // My private instance variable. 
//Supposed to hold  the words in wordList below.

public Sentence(String[] words){ // Constructor which I'm pretty sure is not 100% right
//Elements of array will be words of sentence. 
}

public String shortest() {
    String shortest = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if(shortest.isEmpty())
            shortest = words[i];
        if (shortest.length() > words[i].length())
            shortest = words[i];
    }
    return shortest;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

String[] wordList = {"A", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumped",
             "over", "the", "lazy", "dog"};
Sentence text = new Sentence(wordList);
System.out.println("Shortest word:" + text.shortest());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you are only modifying the constructor's argument variable and not your instance variable. So, just modify the constructor like this:

```
public Sentence(String[] words){ 

this.words = words;

}
```

Note that declaring a local variable with the same name as an instance variable is known as *shadowing*, more informations about that could be found in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing):

> In computer programming, variable shadowing occurs when a variable
>   declared within a certain scope (decision block, method, or inner
>   class) has the same name as a variable declared in an outer scope.

Comment: That literally did it. All of this stress for one simple change. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In your constructor, you need to assign the parameter to your instance variable:

```
public Sentence(String[] words){
    this.words = words;
}
```